# How to find out if variable value has changed? (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In HTML I have this:

```
<input id="Search" type="text" placeholder="Search Images.." ng-model="data" 
       ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)? searchMore() : return">
```

This is basically input field which acts as search.

In controller I just receive the value which is passed to input: `$scope.data`

I want to determine somehow if the search term has changed so that I can wipe out results array if it did or append if just more results of the same search term came.

How to determine that `$scope.data` now contains a different string? If I will just set something like this:

```
$scope.savedData = $scope.data
```

This new variable will be overwritten all the time with new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-change` is one easy way

```
<input id="Search" 
      type="text" 
      placeholder="Search Images.." 
      ng-model="data" 
      ng-change="clearResults()"
      ng-keypress="($event.charCode==13)? searchMore() : return">
```

Comment: ng-change is triggered on every key stroke and I am doing an API call only on keystroke (enter). Doing API calls on every key stroke might not be the best approach.

Comment: @funguy You can use `debounce` for `ng-model-options`, so for example  with `ng-model-options: {debounce: 1000}` when user finish typing it will wait a 1000 miliseconds and then update model and fetch data. Of course it should react as-is on enter. And it depends on you how you implement `clearResults` - it can be simple boolean flag, without call itself. For call you have `searchMore`